# Delphi Week Array Storage Issue for Scheduling System

Tags: arrays, delphi, date, procedure, schedule

I have a form with calenders on it. When the calenders are clicked, they set the variable `CurDateSel` to the date selected on the calendar.

I have a constant array (Week) which has the values of `Monday` [Index 0] through to `Sunday` [Index 6] stored.

I also have a `StringGrid` which used to have the days of the week spanning across the top of the grid, from Sunday to Monday, however, I have now changed that to show the first column of the grid to be the `CurDateSel` day (The `Now` day when the form starts) and the following grid columns to store the days following the day selected.

For example, If Saturday were the day selected:

```
Saturday|Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday
```

I then have a procedure which runs through a stored list of Bookings and adds the bookings with the corresponding day and date to the grid. For example, if a booking was on Sat 23rd at 2pm, the procedure would go to 2pm on the y-axis and go to the 5th column on the axis, as this corresponds to Saturday, in my array WEEK.

However, as my columns now change according to the current day, the stored booking values do not go to the corresponding days, but go to the columns which would normally store the days if the columns started from Monday and ended on Sunday.

I decided to create a new array which would store the values of the week where the start of the week would be the current day and the end of the week would be the current day + 6 days. I called this array `SelDayArray`.

For example, if it were Saturday, this array would start from `Index[0] = Saturday` and end with `Index[6] = Friday`.

I have attempted to write the code to fill this second array, however I seem to have trouble filling it correctly.

```
procedure ReturnUpdatedDay;  
 var  
  i, x, p, CurDayNo: Integer;  
begin  
  i := 0;  
  CurDayNo := ReturnDayCell(FormatDateTime('dddd', CurDateSel));  
  repeat  
    SelDayArray[i] := Week[CurDayNo+i];  
    Inc(i);  
  until (CurDayNo + i) = 7;  
  Dec(i);  
  p := i;  
  for x := 0 to (CurDayNo-p) do  
    begin  
      Inc(i);  
      SelDayArray[i] := Week[x];  
    end;
end;
```

My `ReturnDayCell` Function returns the `DayNo` according to a fixed constant array of the array `WEEK`. Thus, If Saturday were to be selected as the Current Day, the procedure would return `5` and the value of `CurDayNo` would `= 5`

Therefore, my `ReturnUpdatedDay` procedure should set the values of my `SelDayArray` to `TheCurrentDay` `[Index 0]` to `TheCurrentDay+6` `[Index 6]`

This works for the day 'Saturday'.
When I print the list into a memo, I recieve the values: Saturday, Sunday, Monday... Friday.

However, when I try days before saturday, I either receive an access violation error or the last two days of the list are not stored/printed. When I select sunday, I receive an access violation error.

Please could someone give me a hand and help me see what I'm doing wrong. Apologies for any typos or confusing pieces of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mod` operator allows you to *access* the week vector in a circular way, falling back to 0 after the 6th element.

Change your code to this:

```
procedure ReturnUpdatedDay;  
 var  
  I, CurDayNo: Integer;  
begin  
  CurDayNo := ReturnDayCell(FormatDateTime('dddd', CurDateSel));  
  for I := 0 to 6 do
    SelDayArray[I] := Week[(CurDayNo + I) mod 7];  
end;
```